# How to see if a class has a property?

Tags: iphone, ios

I am parsing some xml, and I update the server pretty frequently with new features. So, when I add a new tag or something, my app, which parses the data crashes when I call because the currentElementValue is not part of my class yet. Is there anyway to check if a class has a property, or should I just catch the exception that gets raised?

```
[a setValue:currentElementValue forKey:elementName];
```

Thanks

Answer (score 21):

Very simple:

```
if (class_getProperty([object class], "propertyName")) {
    // it has that property!
}
```

Comment: For iOS, you need to add `#import <objc/message.h>` to your file

Answer (score 8):

If you haven't overridden the standard setter and getter names you can use:

```
 if ([object respondsToSelector:@selector(setProp:)]) {
```

for the setter method of a property called "prop", or:

```
 if ([object respondsToSelector:@selector(prop)]) {
```

for its getter method.

Otherwise, if you used a syntax like:

```
@property (assign, getter=hasProp) BOOL prop;
```

when defining the property, use the corresponding name with the above syntax:

```
 if ([object respondsToSelector:@selector(hasProp)]) {
```

Comment: Not always valid, as a property may define different methods for its getter and setter.

Comment: `@property (assign, getter=isOpen) BOOL open;` - a common pattern

Comment: @Jonathan Grynspan: thanks for your remark. I edited my answer to make more precise and included your insight!

Answer (score 0):

First you need to capitalize the first letter of your property name.

```
NSString *capitalizedProperty = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", [[propertyName substringToIndex:1] uppercaseString], [propertyName substringFromIndex:1]];
```

Then you need to make a selector that would set the property. (If you have a property called "foo" then by default the setter for this property will be called "setFoo:".)

```
SEL propertySetter = NSSelectorFromString([NSString stringWithFormat:@"set%@:",capitalizedProperty]);
```

Then like in sergio's answer, call:

```
if ([object respondsToSelector:propertySetter])
{
    [object setValue:value forKey:propertyName];
}
```

Check [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7284391/automatically-copy-property-values-from-one-object-to-another-of-a-different-typ) to see how to get an object's properties.

Answer (score 0):

for Swift5

```
if class_getProperty([object class], "propertyName") != nil {
    // it has that property!
}
```