# Copying Inherited Values in Objective C

Tags: objective-c, class, inheritance

I've got the following classes.

```
@interface classB : classA

@property NSString* token;


@end

@interface classA 

@property NSString* name;
@property float email;

@end
```

I basically want to create an instance of classB whose inherited (classA) is a copy of another instance of classA. Without having to do the copying manually for each property.

I've tried copyWithZone but I don't think that's the right path.

Comment: What makes you think you can copy one class to another without manually doing it?

Comment: If they're properties it's fairly easy to extract the properties from one and reapply them to the other.  FMDB does it, eg.

Comment: Does inheriting from classA make it any easier?

Comment: Is there any automated way to copy the properties?

Comment: Deleting my answer temporarily while I work out a few kinks.

Comment: Okay, fixed and got rid of deprecation warnings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not believe there is a way to do this auto-magically.  However, based on the answer to this question ([Automatically Copy Property Values...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7284391/automatically-copy-property-values-from-one-object-to-another-of-a-different-typ)), I was able to come up with a fairly simple method you could use.

First, assuming your classes inherit from NSObject, add a category to NSObject with the following method (or, you could just add this method to Class A):

```
#import <objc/runtime.h>

- (NSSet *)propertyNames
{
    NSMutableSet *propNames = [NSMutableSet set];
    unsigned int outCount, i;
    objc_property_t *properties = class_copyPropertyList([self class], &outCount);
    for (i = 0; i < outCount; i++) {
        objc_property_t property = properties[i];
        NSString *propertyName = [[NSString alloc] initWithCString:property_getName(property) encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        [propNames addObject:propertyName];
    }
    free(properties);

    return propNames;
}
```

That will get you an `NSSet *` of all the property names as `NSString`s.

Then, for Class B, create the following method that will take Class A as in input, initialize an instance of Class B, iterate through Class A's property names, and copy them to Class B.

```
- (id)initWithClassA:(ClassA *)classA
{
    self = [super init];

    if(self)
    {
        NSSet *propertyNames = [classA propertyNames];

        for(NSString *propertyKey in propertyNames)
        {
            id value = [classA valueForKey:propertyKey];
            [self setValue:[value copy] forKey:propertyKey];
        }
    }

    return self;
}
```